# How to get specific rows on conditions?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, row, slice

For the data as like follows:

```
Name      Stage           Start                 End

Hulk        1      21/10/2018 06:34:15    21/10/2018 07:34:15
Hulk        2      21/10/2018 07:34:15    21/10/2018 07:54:15
Hulk        3      21/10/2018 07:58:15    21/10/2018 08:14:15
Hulk        4      21/10/2018 08:14:15    21/10/2018 08:34:15
Sam         A1     21/10/2018 09:34:15    21/10/2018 10:34:15
Sam         A2     21/10/2018 10:34:15    21/10/2018 10:45:15
Sam         A3     21/10/2018 10:45:15    21/10/2018 11:00:15
Sam         A4     21/10/2018 11:00:15    21/10/2018 11:34:15
Bruce       1.1    21/10/2018 11:34:15    21/10/2018 11:45:15
Bruce       1.2    21/10/2018 11:45:15    21/10/2018 12:00:15
Bruce       1.3    21/10/2018 12:00:15    21/10/2018 12:25:15
Bruce       1.4    21/10/2018 12:25:15    21/10/2018 12:45:15
Peter        1     21/10/2018 12:45:15    21/10/2018 01:05:15
Peter        1     21/10/2018 01:05:15    21/10/2018 01:15:15
```

How can I have `first` and `last` instance of `Stage` for each `Name` like  which are starting with `1` in it and lasting with `4` ?

The dataframe should be in following way :

```
Name      Stage           Start                 End

Hulk        1      21/10/2018 06:34:15    21/10/2018 07:34:15
Hulk        4      21/10/2018 08:14:15    21/10/2018 08:34:15
Sam         A1     21/10/2018 09:34:15    21/10/2018 10:34:15
Sam         A4     21/10/2018 11:00:15    21/10/2018 11:34:15
Bruce       1.1    21/10/2018 11:34:15    21/10/2018 11:45:15
Bruce       1.4    21/10/2018 12:25:15    21/10/2018 12:45:15
```

I tried `groupby` with `([Name,Stage])` but didn't get desired dataframe as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for return necessary rows first and then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for filter only 2 row groups:

```
m1 = ~df['Name'].duplicated()
m2 = df['Stage'].str.contains('1')

m3 = ~df['Name'].duplicated(keep='last')
m4 = df['Stage'].str.contains('4')

df1 = df[(m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4)].copy()

df1 = df1[df1['Name'].map(df1['Name'].value_counts()) == 2]
print (df1)
     Name Stage                Start                  End
0    Hulk     1  21/10/2018 06:34:15  21/10/2018 07:34:15
3    Hulk     4  21/10/2018 08:14:15  21/10/2018 08:34:15
4     Sam    A1  21/10/2018 09:34:15  21/10/2018 10:34:15
7     Sam    A4  21/10/2018 11:00:15  21/10/2018 11:34:15
8   Bruce   1.1  21/10/2018 11:34:15  21/10/2018 11:45:15
11  Bruce   1.4  21/10/2018 12:25:15  21/10/2018 12:45:15
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Use `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')` - separator is regex 2 or more whitespaces

Comment: Thanks a TON sir, it helped me. You are AWESOME.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks jezrael for the lovely solution, really admire your conceptual strength : )